# Clips: Restriction in the variable of a vector to search

Tags: clips

This is the Clips code that i am trying to arrange. I have some vector in de BH and I want to search among them, those which ?P is common between them. Moreover in the second vector to search the restriction is that ?E can only be that types. Please help me.

`(defrule padre
(es-padre ?P ?H)
(?E & :(tigre | leopardo | jirafa | cebra | avestruz | pinguino | albatros) ?P)
=>
(assert (?E ?H))
)`

Is there any solution implementing a Switch case, or the unique solution is making more rules?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple syntax errors, so it's hard to tell what you're trying to do. To start, the first field of a pattern or fact you're asserting can't be a variable. If you include examples in your question (such as the facts you're asserting and what should happen when your rule executes) it will make it easier to answer your question.